# How to use local(project folder) installed ionic version instead global

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having older ionic version which installed  globally using **-g** option. 
For the new project i have installed new ionic version without **-g** option.

```
 npm install ionic@latest
```

If i try to run any ionic commands, It was always using the globally installed ionic version. **Is it possible to point locally installed version?**

Because, i do not want to update the ionic for the old project.

Comment: it wont affect your project ionic version.. that is `ionic-angular` package in package.json.. what you are installing globally is the cli

Comment: @suraj rao, i am getting error, if try to use ionic serve command

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/388#issuecomment-97237198 according to this its not possible to do a local install

Comment: also check https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2429

Answer (score 8):

If you run `npm install` then there should be a `.bin` folder in your `node_modules`. If you have a different version of Ionic specified in your `package.json` then there should be a file `ionic` inside the .bin folder.

Example of the [ionic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic) entry in the `devDependencies` in the package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "^3.0.0",
}
```

To use this version of Ionic you can simply run:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ionic <your_ionic_command_here>
```

Comment: In Windows I have to use backslash to work properly, Ex: `.\node_modules\.bin\ionic <your_ionic_command_here>`